# Dúvida com arquivos de estilos (styles.xml) no Android

Tags: android-layout

No Android é possível fazer vários arquivos de estilo, um para cada versão do nível de `API` (16, 19, 21...), para cada tipo de tela (xxxdp) e etc. Mas me surgiu uma dúvida: existe algum tipo de herança entre esses arquivos?

Por exemplo: estou trabalhando em um projeto onde o nível mínimo de `API` é 16 (`JellyBean`). Para isso, estou com 3 arquivos de estilos: um para a `API 16`, um para a `API 19` e um para a `API 21`. Porém, dentro desses arquivos, estou definindo a mesma coisa (bem dizendo) 3 vezes:

**API 21:**

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor">
        <item name="">@color/blue_500</item>
        <item name="">@color/blue_700</item>
        <item name="">@color/amber_a700</item>
        <!--<item name="">true</item>-->
        <item name="alertDialogProTheme">@style/Theme.AlertDialogPro.Material.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkToolbar" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**API 19:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/amber_a700</item>
        <item name="">true</item>
        <!--<item name="">true</item>-->
        <item name="alertDialogProTheme">@style/Theme.AlertDialogPro.Material.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkToolbar" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

API 16:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/amber_a700</item>
        <!--<item name="">true</item>-->
        <item name="alertDialogProTheme">@style/Theme.AlertDialogPro.Material.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkToolbar" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="">/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Minha dúvida é: se eu definir apenas uma vez as cores usadas no `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark` e `colorAccent`, bem como definir apenas uma vez o estilo `DarkToolbar`, eu preciso redefini-los para cada verão de API, em outras palavras, atribuir novamente os valores para cada versão do Android que meu aplicativo suporta?

Edição: ao tentar rodar o aplicativo utilizando os XMLs acima, recebi um erro informando que eu deveria usar o tema "AppCompat" ao invés do tema "Material", porém o telefone que estou testando é API 21 (Android 5.0), deveria suportar o tema Material. Alguma dica do que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que se todos os seus estilos derivam de `AppCompat` você pode usar um atributo padrão para ser utilizado em todos os estilos. Abaixo lhe mostro um exemplo bem simples.

### strings.xml (API: 21)

```
<resources>
    <string name="text_info">Minha API é 21!!!</string>
</resources>
```

### strings.xml (API: 19)

```
<resources>
    <string name="text_info">Minha API é 19+!!!</string>
</resources>
```

### strings.xml (API: Padrão)

```
<resources>
    <string name="text_info">Minha API não é 19 e nem 21</string>
    <string name="text_info2">Esse texto vai ser mostrado em todas as APIS!</strings>
</resources>
```

---

Acima, você pode ver que cada XML tem uma string com o conteúdo diferente. Porém na `XML` padrão, temos um `text_info2` que não aparece nas outras `XML`. Quando você mostrar este texto, o sistema vai verificar se as configurações para API 21 possuem esse texto, se não possuir, ele vai mostrar o texto padrão. E... voltando ao assunto: sim, quando você colocar um valor padrão em sua configuração de estilo, ***se não houver uma configuração para sua API atual***, o sistema vai utilizar o valor da `API` padrão.

Comment: Obrigado, array! Era exatamente essa minha dúvida.